# Sum of Counted records that calculated using "group by" with condition and "group by"

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, left-join

I'm sorry for fuzzy title of this question.

I have 2 Tables in my database and want to count records of first_table using "group by" on a foreign key id that exists in a column of second_table (which stores ids like array "1,2,3,4,5").

### id   |   name    |   fk_id

```
 1    |   john    |     1
 2    |   mike    |     1
 3    |   jane    |     2
 4    |   tailor  |     1
 5    |   jane    |     3
 6    |   tailor  |     5
 7    |   jane    |     4
 8    |   tailor  |     5
 9    |   jane    |     5
 10   |   tailor  |     5
```

### id   |   name    |   fk_ids   |  s_fk_id

```
 1    |    xxx    |  1,5,6     |     1
 2    |    yyy    |  2,3       |     1
 3    |    zzz    |  9         |     1
 4    |    www    |  7,8       |     1
```

Now i wrote the following query but it not working properly and displays wrong numbers.

I WANT TO:

1-Count records in first_table group by "fk_id"

2-Sum the counted records which exists in  "fk_ids"

3-Display the sum result (sum of related counts) grouped by id.

symbol ' ' means ``.

```
select sum(if(FIND_IN_SET('fk_id', 'fk_ids')>0,'count',0) 'sum', 'count', 'from'.'fk_id', 'second_table'.* FROM 'second_table'
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'fk_id', count(*) 'count'
    FROM 'first_table'
    group BY 'fk_id'
 ) AS 'from'
ON FIND_IN_SET('fk_id', 'fk_ids')>0
WHERE  'second_table'.'s_fk_id'=1
GROUP BY 'id'
ORDER by 'count' DESC
```

This table has many data and we have no plan to change the structure.

**Edit:**

Desired output:

### id   |   name    |    sum

```
 1    |    xxx    | 7  (3+4+0)
 2    |    yyy    | 2  (1+1)  
 3    |    zzz    | 0  (0)    
 4    |    www    | 0  (0+0)
```

Comment: `from` is a poor table alias... Avoid SQL keywords!

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. MySQL uses backticks for delimited identifers. (ANSI SQL uses double quotes.)

Comment: Why are the foreign keys in an array to begin with? The data is not normalized and this problem will only get worse going forward. Can you fix the design?

Comment: @jarlh I know and i wrote the query like this for example.

Comment: @JacobH No there this is a huge work and designed to a purpose to satisfy the requirement just with configuration (i said this to explain the complexity). and there are a lot of this abnormal structures.

Comment: @JacobH How to just reach this target with SQL queries. God will help us for next challenges :D

Comment: Could you share an example of your desired output?

Comment: @AlvaroNiño I edited the question and added the desired output. (the pranteses inside "sum" column is just for description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two holidays i came back to work and found out that the "FIND_IN_SET" function is not working properly with space contained string.

And the problem is that i was ignored the spaces too, (same as this question)

Finnaly this query worked:

```
select sum(`count`) `sum`, `count`, `from`.`fk_id`, `second_table`.* FROM `second_table`
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT `fk_id`, count(*) `count`
    FROM `first_table`
    group BY `fk_id`
 ) AS `from`
ON FIND_IN_SET(`fk_id`, replace(`fk_ids`,' ',''))>0
WHERE  `second_table`.`s_fk_id`=1
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER by `count` DESC
```

And the magic is `replace(fk_ids,' ','')`